# Tensorflow Reducing Batch dimension | timeseries_dataset_from_array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to get `(None,7)` shape from `tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array` but it returns shape `(None, None,7)`.

tensorflow don't allow to set `batch_size=None` or `batch_size=0` to reduce the batch_size dimension.

So is there any way to ravel/reduce that dimension?

> PS: I am trying the fit it to my custom layer which accepts only data of n_dim of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make 1 batch and get the size of it to be 1, then use [tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) to remove that size 1 dimension? Make sure you specify the correct axis.

Comment: I gave it a shot, on `axis=0` (batch_size axis) but got `ValueError` [Screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/4aEuwOxwsUkY.png)